# MigrateSQLMap how to instantiate if table has no primary key

Tags: migrations

Guys how do you instantiate this MigrateSQLMap if my destination table has no primary key?

here's my code:

```
 $table_name = 'taxonomy_index';
    $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
      array('id' => array(
              'type' => 'int',
              'unsigned' => TRUE,
              'not null' => TRUE,
             )
           ),
        MigrateDestinationTable::getKeySchema()
      );
```

im trying to import to the taxonomy_index table in drupal which we know has no primary key.

how to make this possible?

Answer (score 1):

To migrate content into Drupal taxonomy terms, use the MigrateDestinationTerm class, not MigrateDestinationTable. Here is example code

```
    $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap(
      $this->machineName,
      array(
        'term_id' => array(
          'type' => 'int',
          'not null' => TRUE,
          'description' => 'Term ID',
        ),
      ),
      MigrateDestinationTerm::getKeySchema()
    );
```